# How useful are university teaching certifications in faculty hiring?

Tags: teaching, job-search, faculty-application, certification

The university I'm attending for gradaute school offers programs that give you official certification in university teaching. The program consists of taking teaching workshops, participating in teaching sessions, and things like this.

My question is, how much attention would a hiring committee pay to something like this, on a scale from "don't care at all" to "mildly care about it"? I certainly don't expect it to be a big factor, but I want to understand how much of a factor it is.

Comment: Is this a UK specific thing? I've never encountered it in US.

Comment: Canadian university.

Comment: @Buffy [Here](https://mcgraw.princeton.edu/graduate-students/teaching-transcript) is an example in the US.

Comment: And are you asking about how universities in Canada would care about it, or in other places?  E.g., Dawn's answer addresses how it might be viewed in the US (which matches my expectations from the US also).

Comment: This will depend on the nature of the job the committee is trying to fill.  For some types of positions, this will be very relevant, and others, not so much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was at a name-brand R1 (in the US) and did one of these certificates. In my experience, more teaching-oriented positions (SLAC and R2, mostly) saw it as a positive signal of my commitment to teaching vs research only (which would usually be assumed given my university). It was especially useful since my university didn’t let students work as instructors of record and TA appointments were also pretty rare.

I was often asked about it and I was told by certain faculty that it assuaged concerns about using an interview slot for someone from my university. After that point, it was more about the answers I gave to teaching-oriented questions that got me through…which I felt the teaching certificate helped me prepare for in terms of my knowledge of pedagogy etc.

Comment: "Name-brand R1" made me chuckle. :)

Answer (score 13):

In the UK, some universities require new faculty members to complete one of these certifications as a condition of passing probation.  If you've already got a certification at a sufficient level [*] from your previous institution, that can save you some time and effort during a period when you would, in any case, be very busy.

[*] There are two levels of certification in the UK: one leading to associateship of the Higher Education Academy, one leading to fellowship of the Higher Education Academy.

Comment: Nice. But this does not answer the question. OP asked about *advantage in the hiring process*.

Comment: @Dilworth I read into this answer:  1. it is unlikely to help you in the hiring process; 2. if it does help you in the hiring process, it will only be by a small amount.

Comment: @emory Depends if you consider probation part of the "hiring process".

Comment: Basically, for how much it helps in the hiring process: little to none, but it does allow you to tick a box that you wouldn't otherwise be able to tick, and sadly the UK hiring process sometimes is a creative exercise in box-ticking (because being able to present a decision based on very specific criteria scored with 1/2/3 points makes it straightforward to defend from any discrimination charges...)

Comment: It could help in the UK hiring process, depending on what they list on the essential/desirable criteria in the job notice. I have seen many job notices list AFHEA/FHEA as being a desirable qualification for the applicant, and so having those qualifications means the hiring committee can then use that to short list your application above another candidate that may be equal in other areas but doesn't have that qualification.

Answer (score 7):

If you've earned that certificate then certainly cite it an application for an academic job. It may help and shouldn't hurt.

If you're considering signing up then I suggest you do, because you might become a better teacher - a worthwhile goal whether or not it strengthens a job application some day.

Comment: Some of my European friends have expressed shock that university professors in the US don't normally get any formal training in teaching/pedagogy.

Comment: Many Europeans don't get any training either.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously different individuals, and different hiring committees, will have different responses. On the whole I doubt they will care very much about the certificate itself.

However, if the course helps you think more critically about your teaching, or  introduces you to different ways of doing things, or even just teaches you some pedagogical jargon: it may allow you to write a stronger teaching statement, and talk more intelligently about teaching matters during an interview. This can be a significant advantage, if the school cares about such things.

Answer (score 1):

It will have next to 0 impact if you apply at most Canadian universities.  Canadian institutions (and no doubt others) are desperate to monetize everything they can and show ”value added” for various reporting requirements.

As there is no clear and commonly accepted guidelines on what one is required to do for such certificates, they are largely meaningless except possibly internally. Basically, it’s the Wild West.

As practical examples, many Canadian universities are now creating EDI certificates (Equity, Diversity, Inclusiveness) so that staff can have proof they have completed some EDI training.  Some universities will ask that you participate in “mentoring workshops” in order to supervise graduate students; some give certificate for this as well.  Some now offer certificates of English as second language for international students as a requirement for admission.

Don’t get me wrong: some of the stuff out there is useful.  You can get certificates in a kinds of stuff - say - Excel, Word, basic html, basic Python, etc and you have proof of completion.  However, the value of these would be primarily personal.

If you have heard good things about this or that teaching certificate, then you should consider it as you might get some insights into teaching, resources, some techniques etc, but this would be highly dependent on the actual contents and the instructor.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The certificate/course is sometimes useful for teaching, but meaningless to increase chances of hiring.

Answer (score 0):

Qualification inflation is everywhere in academia.  I think the correct answer to your question is:  Attitudes are changing rapidly.

The concept of teaching certifications seems to have originated with the 1997 [Dearing Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dearing_Report).  Ten years ago, nobody had heard of university teaching certifications, at least in the USA.  The related [CIRTL](https://www.cirtl.net/about) was created in 2003.  The [UKPSF](https://www.heacademy.ac.uk/sites/default/files/resources/UKPSF_Impact_Study_Report.pdf) was introduced in 2006.  I expect that in 10 years, 90% of new faculty will have a certificate, simply because faculty supply exceeds demand in most of higher education.

Comment: 'Ten years ago, nobody had heard of university teaching certifications, at least in the USA.'  You may be right with respect to the USA, but in the UK, I attained my first university teaching certification (Associateship of the Institute for Learning and Teaching in Higher Education) in December 2002.

Comment: And the certification I'm eyeing (in Canada) has been around since '98

Answer (score -2):

Apart from teaching institutions, and teaching oriented colleges, universities etc., such accredited teaching certifications bear **NO** significance, and don't add normally any advantage to your applications.

Hence:

> My question is, how much attention would a hiring committee pay to
> something like this, on a scale from "don't care at all" to "mildly
> care about it"?

the answer is (apart from teaching institutes) "*Don't care at all*"!

Comment: Why not? If one of the main responsibilities of a professor is to teach, then it would seem logical that evidence of teaching ability (like the completion of a relevant accredited program)  should weigh a little.

Comment: Unless someone on the committee is familiar with the program, I think the  certificate *itself* is hard to interpret: they won't know how much work was required for the certificate, how that work was graded, or even the curriculum. Consequently, it's unlikely to get much weight.

That said, participating in *something* teaching-related, accredited or not, does demonstrates your interest/commitment to teaching, which may help, and should prepare you to answer teaching-related questions better.

Comment: This is definitely wrong for the UK and UK-influenced locations.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, not really. It's 100% correct, also in the UK, that having some teaching certificate (e.g. fellow of HE) is completely **meaningless** in THE HIRING PROCESS for research oriented universities. That's what the OP asked about. It is correct that sometimes it is mandatory *once* hired.

Comment: @CSSTUDENT, don't ask me why not. I only stated the facts: committees normally don't really take it into account for hiring for research universities.

Comment: @Dilworth I don’t see a reference to research-oriented universities, but I agree this kind of certification is largely meaningless.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I was just clarifying that my answer is about research universities.